# My implementation of OpenCV bilinear resize is incorrect

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, interpolation

My goal is to implement OpenCV's resize functions (nearest neighbor, bilinear interpolation and bicubic interpolation) by using just python and numpy library. I managed to implement them and create a simple test which indicates that my implementation of bilinear interpolation is incorrect. However, nearest neighbor and bicubic interpolation works as expected. My implementations are made based on the following blog posts: [Nearest neighbor](https://theailearner.com/2018/12/29/image-processing-nearest-neighbour-interpolation/), [Bilinear interpolation](https://theailearner.com/2018/12/29/image-processing-bilinear-interpolation/) and [Bicubic interpolation](https://theailearner.com/tag/bicubic-interpolation/). What am I missing?

**interpolation.py**

```
import numpy as np
import math

def nearest_neighbor(img, fx, fy):
    img_height = img.shape[0]
    img_width = img.shape[1]
    output_height = int(img_height*fy+0.5)
    output_width = int(img_width*fx+0.5)
    x_idx = (np.ceil((np.arange(1, 1 + output_width)-0.5)/fx) - 1).astype(int)
    y_idx = (np.ceil((np.arange(1, 1 + output_height)-0.5)/fy) - 1).astype(int)
    output = img[:, x_idx][y_idx, :]
    return output
    
def bilinear(img, fx, fy):
    img_height = img.shape[0]
    img_width = img.shape[1]
    output_height = int(img_height*fy+0.5)
    output_width = int(img_width*fx+0.5)
    img_pad = np.pad(img,1,mode='edge')
    
    output = np.zeros((output_height, output_width))
    x_weight = (np.arange(output_width) + 0.5)*(1/fx) -0.5
    y_weight = (np.arange(output_height) + 0.5)*(1/fy) -0.5
    x_idx = (np.floor(x_weight)+1).astype(int)
    y_idx = (np.floor(y_weight)+1).astype(int)
    x_weight2 = x_weight - np.floor(x_weight)
    y_weight2 = y_weight - np.floor(y_weight)
    for i in range(output_width):
        for j in range(output_height):
            A = (1-x_weight2[i]) * img_pad[y_idx[j],x_idx[i]] + x_weight2[i] * img_pad[y_idx[j],x_idx[i]+1]
            B = (1-x_weight2[i]) * img_pad[y_idx[j]+1,x_idx[i]] + x_weight2[i] * img_pad[y_idx[j]+1,x_idx[i]+1]
            output[j,i] = A*(1-y_weight2[j]) + B*y_weight2[j]
    output = np.rint(output)
    return output
    
def bicubic(img, fx, fy):
    def coefficients(z):
        coeff0 = -0.75*(z**3) + 1.5*(z**2) - 0.75*z
        coeff1 = 1.25*(z**3) - 2.25*(z**2) + 1
        coeff2 = -1.25*(z**3) + 1.5*(z**2) + 0.75*z
        coeff3 = 1.0 - coeff0 - coeff1 - coeff2
        return coeff0, coeff1, coeff2, coeff3       

    img_height = img.shape[0]
    img_width = img.shape[1]
    output_height = int(img_height*fy+0.5)
    output_width = int(img_width*fx+0.5)
    img_pad = np.pad(img,2,mode='edge')
    
    output = np.zeros((output_height, output_width))
    x_weight = (np.arange(output_width) + 0.5)*(1/fx) -0.5
    y_weight = (np.arange(output_height) + 0.5)*(1/fy) -0.5
    x_idx = (np.floor(x_weight)+1).astype(int)
    y_idx = (np.floor(y_weight)+1).astype(int)
    x_weight2 = x_weight - np.floor(x_weight)
    y_weight2 = y_weight - np.floor(y_weight)
    for i in range(output_width):
        for j in range(output_height):
            x_coeff0, x_coeff1, x_coeff2, x_coeff3 = coefficients(x_weight2[i])
            y_coeff0, y_coeff1, y_coeff2, y_coeff3 = coefficients(y_weight2[j])
            num0 = x_coeff0 * img_pad[y_idx[j],x_idx[i]] + x_coeff1 * img_pad[y_idx[j],x_idx[i]+1] + x_coeff2 * img_pad[y_idx[j],x_idx[i]+2] + x_coeff3 * img_pad[y_idx[j],x_idx[i]+3]
            num1 = x_coeff0 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+1,x_idx[i]] + x_coeff1 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+1,x_idx[i]+1] + x_coeff2 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+1,x_idx[i]+2] + x_coeff3 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+1,x_idx[i]+3]
            num2 = x_coeff0 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+2,x_idx[i]] + x_coeff1 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+2,x_idx[i]+1] + x_coeff2 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+2,x_idx[i]+2] + x_coeff3 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+2,x_idx[i]+3]
            num3 = x_coeff0 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+3,x_idx[i]] + x_coeff1 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+3,x_idx[i]+1] + x_coeff2 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+3,x_idx[i]+2] + x_coeff3 * img_pad[y_idx[j]+3,x_idx[i]+3]
            output[j,i] = num0*y_coeff0 + num1*y_coeff1 + num2*y_coeff2 + num3*y_coeff3
    output = np.rint(output)
    return output
```

Test file calculates the difference between OpenCV's resize and my implementation from two different input a and b and for three different scales x2, x2.5 and x3.

**tests.py**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import interpolation

def do_tests(a, b, interpolation_opencv, interpolation_implemented):
    print("Test 1")
    img1 = cv2.resize(a,(0,0),fx=2,fy=2,interpolation=interpolation_opencv)
    img2 = interpolation_implemented(a,2,2)
    print(img2-img1)

    print("Test 2")
    img1 = cv2.resize(a,(0,0),fx=2.5,fy=2.5,interpolation=interpolation_opencv)
    img2 = interpolation_implemented(a,2.5,2.5)
    print(img2-img1)

    print("Test 3")
    img1 = cv2.resize(a,(0,0),fx=3,fy=3,interpolation=interpolation_opencv)
    img2 = interpolation_implemented(a,3,3)
    print(img2-img1)

    print("Test 4")
    img1 = cv2.resize(b,(0,0),fx=2,fy=2,interpolation=interpolation_opencv)
    img2 = interpolation_implemented(b,2,2)
    print(img2-img1)

    print("Test 5")
    img1 = cv2.resize(b,(0,0),fx=2.5,fy=2.5,interpolation=interpolation_opencv)
    img2 = interpolation_implemented(b,2.5,2.5)
    print(img2-img1)

    print("Test 6")
    img1 = cv2.resize(b,(0,0),fx=3,fy=3,interpolation=interpolation_opencv)
    img2 = interpolation_implemented(b,3,3)
    print(img2-img1)
    
a = np.array([[10,20],[30,40]], dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array([[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]], dtype=np.uint8)

print("\nTests for nearest neighbor interpolation:")
do_tests(a,b,cv2.INTER_NEAREST, interpolation.nearest_neighbor)
print("\nTests for bilinear interpolation:")
do_tests(a,b,cv2.INTER_LINEAR, interpolation.bilinear)
print("\nTests for biccubic interpolation:")
do_tests(a,b,cv2.INTER_CUBIC, interpolation.bicubic)
```

After running the test file, my terminal outputs:

```
Tests for nearest neighbor interpolation:
Test 1
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
Test 2
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
Test 3
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
Test 4
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
Test 5
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
Test 6
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

Tests for bilinear interpolation:
Test 1
[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]]
Test 2
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Test 3
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
Test 4
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]]
Test 5
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Test 6
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

Tests for biccubic interpolation:
Test 1
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Test 2
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Test 3
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Test 4
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Test 5
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Test 6
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: how does your test indicate this?

Comment: If you run the test file, which calculates the difference between OpenCV's resize and my implementation from two different input a and b and for three different scales x2, x2.5 and x3, you can see a couple of errors. The errors occurs just for bilinear resize and I cannot imagine the reason for that.

Comment: are those rounding errors? have you considered that opencv may not be precise?

Comment: Its true that my implementation can be more precise but how can I confirm that? A follow-up question, if opencv is not precise, can I still mimic this imprecise behavior?

Comment: I'm not saying more or less precise. I'm saying this could just be rounding differences. I'll assume your value range is 0..255, so then a difference of 1 *can be* purely an effect of numerics (computers have limited precision of course).

Comment: I got your point. Yes, my value range is between 0-255 since arrays are in uint8 format. So do I have to just admit that I cannot fully mimic the behavior of opencv's bilinear resize or is there for example a way to test opencv's rounding?

Comment: I'd say you *did* reproduce it well enough. if you feel like it, look into machine arithmetic and sources of error in floating point arithmetic (hint: not always (x+y)+z == x+(y+z)). OpenCV has some efforts to nail algorithms down to be "bit-exact" in their outputs. not sure if that covers bilinear resampling.